# importing polymer behavior in polymerTS

Tags: typescript, polymer, web-component

So I'm using PolymerTS to use TypeScript with my polymer web app, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to import existing behaviors present into my components.

For example, if I wanted to use IronControlState in my component in a normal polymer component I would:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html">

<template code>

Polymer({
 is: 'example-component',
 properties: {
   name: {stype: String},
   value: {type: String},
   valueShort: {
 },
 behaviors: [
   Polymer.IronControlState,
           ],
```

The documentation for PolymerTS says I'm supposed to just use a decorator @behavior to add a behavior to my component. This if fine if the behavior is defined in some TypeScript code imported in my ts code. But for behaviors built into Polymer, I'm lost.

If I just try:

```
declare var Polymer: {IronControlState: {focused: boolean} };

@component('example-component')
@behavior(Polymer.IronControlState)
export class ExampleComponent extends polymer.Base {
```

with the same imports in my HTML, I get the following error in my browser's console:

```
[example-component::_flattenBehaviorsList]: behavior is null, check for missing or 404 import
```

which suggests to me that it's not finding the behavior I'm asking for...

However, Polymer.IronControlState is definitely being loaded. From the .ts I can add:

```
ready() {
  console.log(Polymer.IronControlState);
}
```

and it outputs: Object {properties: Object, observers: Array[1]}

But if I try to log this.focused it outputs 'undefined'.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: I should add the template code and html imports are unchanged from javascript to typescript. I've just removed the js and added a .ts file. The .ts file compiles and works correctly except for the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that adding behaviors was only supported from TypeScript Classes. The latest revision has added a fix to support behaviors from generic functions:

https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS/issues/56

Answer (score 0):

> which suggests to me that it's not finding the behavior I'm asking for...

Indeed. You still need to put `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html">` in your template.

Comment: It is still in my template.